# Grep lines from a file that respect two conditions

Tags: awk, grep, conditional-statements

I have a file that looks like:

```
Condition1 name
Condition2
Condition2
Condition2
Condition3
.
.
Condition1 name
Condition2
Condition2
Condition2
Condition3
```

I would like to grep it in order to have:

```
Condition1 name
Condition2
Condition2
Condition2
Condition1 name
Condition2
Condition2
Condition2
```

So I would like to awk the lines after Condition1 match (including Condition1 line) while Condition2 is True and skip to the next line where Condition1 matches again.

Comment: You are probably better off using sed or awk as it has a concept of state which grep does not. In any case what have you tried?

Comment: `I would like to awk the lines` - what does it mean to "awk the lines"? Why not just `grep 'Condition1\|Condition2'`?

Comment: a bit unclear, like this? `awk '/Condition1/{a[i++]=$0}/Condition2/{a[i++]=$0}END{for (i in a){print a[i]}}' INPUT`

Comment: People thank you and sorry if I was not clear at all. I guessed it is a website open to people who has not a proper background. For example I don't know the difference between awk, sed and grep. I always used solutions that worked for my purpose. Anyway. I tried the grep but it doesn't work in my case since I need that specific pattern, not that generally one of the two conditions is True. I will try the other ones, even though a bit blindly not having knowledge of what the different commands and keywords mean!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that Condition1 and Condition2 stand for generic awk expression (might be '$3 = "FOO"`, and not simple regexp, therefore`grep`and`sed` not an option.

Verbose solution, P set to 1, when in 'print' region.

```
awk '
{
    if ( /Condition1/ ) {
        P=1
    } else {
        if ( ! /Condition2/ ) {
            P=0
        }
    } ;
    if ( P ) print
}
'
```

Or as more compact one liner

```
awk '{ /Condition1/ ? P=1 : ! /Condition2/  ? P=0 :  1 } P { print }'
```